# Swift signal SIGABRT error on UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, sigabrt

Currently working on a graduation project on Swift (beginner) and i have encountered interesting error that i couldn't solve. I made my research but couldn't find anything useful. I am using `UITableView` for my project and every tab is similar to each other. Only difference is JSON url. Every page is working well but one page gives [`signal SIGABRT`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1LUw.png) error at appdelegate.

Even though i have deleted everything at [`UIViewController`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPoSG.png), it still gives same error so i think its something deep. I admit that because of the similarities of the pages i might copy paste some labels to new View. Probably thats the case i have to deal with but i can't figure it out. I have checked the connections on the last bar at the right side of the panel, everything seems okay.

Edit: 
Here what it says on console when it crashes. [Console Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lX4Eg.png)

Comment: There should be an error message in the debug console (see there: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/debugging_tools.html at the right bottom of the first screenshot) . Read it. If you don't understand it, show it here at least, we can guide you through another questions with the same issue or post an answer.

Comment: Add exception breakpoint, enable debug and run app. So that you'll get the exact line from where it is crashing..!!

Comment: I have closed that part of console somehow and couldn't find where to open it again, but i opened it with your reference so thank you. [Here what it says](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IwN6A.png)

Comment: the error state, that UITableViewCell doesn't have a property called facultyLabel, so probably you need to set the class in your nib/storyboard file to your custom cell class, which inherited from UITableViewCell.

Comment: Inherit Module From target was unchecked, that was the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two mistakes from the log you attached:

- `Unknown class TeacherCell` means that you probably assigned to a
  UITableViewCell the custom class named TeacherCell, but this class
  does not exist (or it's called in another way).
- `this class is not key value code-compliant for the key
  facultyNameLabel` means that you probably have a label named
  facultyNameLabel in your storyboard/XIB but it is not present in the
  related swift file. Try to ctrl-click in every cell of your tableview
  and search for a yellow triangle.

Comment: After you said TeacherCell not exists, i double checked but it seems that its true but i delete and re-write again and [this was](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41v4i.png) the problem. Before i write the name again, `Inherit Module From Target` was not checked. It auto checked when i write it again and it works perfectly now. Now this [errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVUWT.png) left behind. Do you know what are these?

Comment: Unknown class in Interface builder file is my silly mistake. I rename `FirstViewController` into something else and forget to change.